# rake task for webpush notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-worker

I have in **challenge_reminder.rake**

```
task challenge_reminder: :environment do
  Challenge.unaccomplished.all.each do |challenge|
    if challenge.remind.include? Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[Date.current.wday].downcase
        if challenge.mail == true # This Works
            UserMailer.challenge_reminder(challenge).deliver_now 
        end
        if challenge.push == true 
          # How to send webpush notification for challenge
        end 
    end      
  end 
end
```

The user can receive a push notification if he manually clicks the button...

```
<%= content_tag(:button, "Foo", class: "webpush-button") %>

<script>
  $('.webpush-button').on('click', (e) => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
      serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then((subscription) => {
        console.log('Almost there, Daddy!');
        $.post('/push', {
          subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
          message: 'You clicked a button!'
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

leading to...

```
class PushNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def push
    Webpush.payload_send(
      message: params[:message],
      endpoint: params[:subscription][:endpoint],
      p256dh: params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh],
      auth: params[:subscription][:keys][:auth],
      vapid: {
        subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
        public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
        private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
      }
    )
  end
end
```

How can I adjust the script code for the rake task?

I implemented push via [serviceworker gem](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails), [webpush gem](https://github.com/zaru/webpush), and VAPID credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move whole logic from PushNotificationsController#push to some domain logic or maybe service - `PushNotificationsService` which could be used from diff places:

```
class PushNotificationsService
  def self.call(params) 
    Webpush.payload_send(
      message: params[:message],
      endpoint: params[:subscription][:endpoint],
      p256dh: params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh],
      auth: params[:subscription][:keys][:auth],
      vapid: {
        subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
        public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
        private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
      } 
    )
  end
end
```

Then you can call this service from diff places in your app, ie. `PushNotificationsService.call(params)`

Hope this helps !